# SELECT on MySQL doesn't work on my PHP script but with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a MySQL table with a VARBINARY 257 to store crypted passwords. I have to update records regularly. Before to make a REPLACE INTO, I would like to make a SELECT with all the values I have. If I find a record, REPLACE is not necessary. It's because I have a timestamp column with an "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" attribute to store last modification time. It works well when there's no password, but even if all values are the same, SELECT doesn't work. If I use same SELECT on phpmyadmin, it works. I have a function to read records in which I've tried mysqli functions and PDO class :

mysqli :

```
function getMySQL($query, $pwd) {
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "decisionrule", $pwd, "gateways");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        return array(array('Connection error : '.mysqli_connect_error()));
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $res = array();
    for ($i=0; $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); $i++)
        $res[$i] = $row;
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($link);
    return $res;
}
```

PDO :

```
function getMySQL($query, $pwd) {
    try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gateways', "decisionrule", $pwd);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage()."\n");
    }
    $res = array();
    $response = $bdd->query($query);
    while ($donnees = $response->fetch())
        $res[] = $donnees;
    $response->closeCursor();
    return $res;
}
```

Returns an empty array for my issue.

Example of a SELECT :

```
SELECT name FROM partenaires WHERE gateway='GTWEIR01' AND name='ACCOLADE' AND proto_ident='ACCOLADE' AND protocol='SFTP' AND comments='ACCOLADE - SA0000026603841' AND login_ident='cofidisacco' AND login_password=0x014f4593f6e4360b4c4905da27e3a912e9e8f641ca96557ef1a7e7c10f44273d56c661107d1983d47a9f822e2e419c295b791dd4aed54fe57a4bcd44130f475c4673ec14d044ce208e84bd6a447161874746567e5446388883bbe3a3b8ddb75155488e8290fc5850cfcd776edf9994819e85d1fcec8b4ba3e02c2081a440172b AND dest_address='90.83.11.173/22' AND org_address='' AND dest_address_1='41.87.153.85/22' AND org_address_1='' AND dest_address_2='' AND org_address_2='' AND dest_address_3='' AND org_address_3=''
```

Is there a size limit for SELECT that can be changed because it works on phpmyadmin ?

Versions :

```
RedHat 6
PHP 5.3.3
Apache 2.2.15
MySQL 5.1.73
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you added some error handling after firing the query, then you would perhaps know what went wrong and would not be in such a limbo.

Comment: type login_password into quotes ' '

Comment: @Shadow I've tried with mysqli and tested $result. It's never false.

Comment: @Leet I've tried with quotes. That's not better and it doesn't explain why it works with phpmyadmin.

Comment: max_allowed_packet is set to 1MB so it seems it's not a query size limit problem

Comment: In that case there is no matching record. If you believe that to be incorrect, then pls share some sample data and query that produces unexpected results, so we can see for ourselves what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched a long time, more than one whole day, without finding out what was wrong. And it was so simple. I'm using RSA public key to crypt password and, even if password hasn't be changed, crypting has each time another result. So my SELECT can't be successfull.

I must apologize for wasting your precious time.

Special thanks to Shadow and Leet Hudka.